# Erlang exception error: no true branch found when evaluating an if expression

Tags: erlang

I don't understand erlang very well and for the past number of hours I've been searching up ways to fix this but I can't find any good If statement examples.

I'm trying to use a recursive function to move discs from one hanoi tower to another. However I get the "no true branch found when evaluating an if expression". I understand as far as needing `true ->` somewhere?

```
-module(hanoi).

-export([main/1]).

%% Create Towers
main(NumDiscs) ->
    TowerA = create_tower(NumDiscs),
    TowerB = [],
    TowerC = [],
    display_towers(TowerA,TowerB,TowerC),
    solve(NumDiscs,TowerA,TowerB,TowerC).

%% Add the number of discs inputted to the first tower  
create_tower(0) -> [];

create_tower(NumDiscs) when NumDiscs > 0 ->
    [NumDiscs] ++ create_tower(NumDiscs - 1).

%% Display all towers
display_towers(A,B,C) ->
    io:format("-------------------------\n"),
    io:format("Tower A: ~p\n",[A]),
    io:format("Tower B: ~p\n",[B]),
    io:format("Tower C: ~p\n",[C]).


solve(Disc,TowA,TowB,TowC) ->
if Disc > 0 ->
    solve(Disc - 1,TowA,TowB,TowC),
    TowBNew = [lists:last(TowA)],
    TowCNew = [lists:append(TowC,TowBNew)],
    TowANew = [lists:sublist(TowA,length(TowA) - 1)],
    display_towers(TowANew,TowB,TowCNew),
    solve(Disc - 1,TowANew,TowCNew,TowB)
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

An `if` expression in Erlang *must* have a branch that evaluates to true. I'm guessing that error is thrown when `Disc > 0` is false. You need to add a `true ->` clause to that:

```
solve(Disc,TowA,TowB,TowC) ->
  if Disc > 0 ->
    solve(Disc - 1,TowA,TowB,TowC),
    TowBNew = [lists:last(TowA)],
    TowCNew = [lists:append(TowC,TowBNew)],
    TowANew = [lists:sublist(TowA,length(TowA) - 1)],
    display_towers(TowANew,TowB,TowCNew),
    solve(Disc - 1,TowANew,TowCNew,TowB); % <- note the ';'
  true ->
    % do something here
end.
```

Comment: Do I have to put something between true -> and end. ?

Comment: Thing is, Disc is passed down from main(NumDiscs) I usually enter 3 for testing, so I'm not sure why it's tripping on the first run

Comment: The first thing your function does is call itself with `Disc - 1`. When it reaches 1, the condition is true, and it calls itself with 0. That's when it fails.

Comment: Between `true ->` and `end` you put the result you want to get in this case (i.e. if `Disc > 0` is false).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code from a long time ago. Hope this can help you:

```
main(N)->
    towerhanoi(N, a, b, c).
towerhanoi(N, A, C, B)->
    case N of
        1 ->
            change(N, A, C);
        _ ->
            towerhanoi(N-1, A, B, C),
            change(N, A, C),
            towerhanoi(N-1 , B, C, A)
    end.
change(N, A, C)->
    io:format("change disc ~p from tower ~p to tower ~p~n", [N, A, C]).
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) unfortunately I also get the same error :(